# MySQL evaluating results

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, subquery, statements

I have a funny MySQL query that needs to pull a subquery from another table, I'm wondering if this is even possible to get mysql to evaluate the subquery.

example:
(I had to replace some brackets with 'gte' & 'lte' cause they were screwing up the post format)

```
select a.id,a.alloyname,a.label,a.symbol, g.grade,
    if(a.id = 1,(
        (((select avg(cost/2204.6) as averageCost from nas_cost where cost != '0' and `date` lte '2011-03-01' and `date` gte '2011-03-31') - t.value) * (astm.astm/100) * 1.2)
    ),(a.formulae)) as thisValue
from nas_alloys a 
left join nas_triggers t on t.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_astm astm on astm.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_estimatedprice ep on ep.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_grades g on g.id = astm.gradeid
where a.id = '1' or a.id = '2'
order by g.grade;
```

So when the IF statement is not = '1' then the (a.formulae) is the value in the nas_alloys table which is:

```
((ep.estPrice - t.value) * (astm.astm/100) * 0.012)
```

Basically I want this query to run as:

```
select a.id,a.alloyname,a.label,a.symbol, g.grade,
    if(a.id = 1,(
        (((select avg(cost/2204.6) as averageCost from nas_cost where cost != '0' and `date` gte '2011-03-01' and `date` lte '2011-03-31') - t.value) * (astm.astm/100) * 1.2)
    ),((ep.estPrice - t.value) * (astm.astm/100) * 0.012)) as thisValue
from nas_alloys a 
left join nas_triggers t on t.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_astm astm on astm.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_estimatedprice ep on ep.alloyid = a.id
left join nas_grades g on g.id = astm.gradeid
where a.id = '1' or a.id = '2'
order by g.grade;
```

When a.id != '1', btw, there are about 30 different possibilities for a.formulae, and they change frequently, so hard banging in multiple if statements is not really an option.  [redesigning the business logic is more likely than that!]

Anyway, any thoughts? Will this even work?

-thanks
-sean

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stored Function to compute that value for you, and pass the params you will decide later on. When your business logic changes, you just have to update the Stored Function.

Comment: I don't have access to create functions or stored procs [shared hosting] - can't do that. 

Also - the calculations chnage too frequently - the users have to be able to update them.